# Why does aptitude+multiarch mix up package versions for different architectures?

Tags: aptitude, multiarch

I am on a amd64 architecture, with another foreign architecture arm64 also installed. When installing a certain package, it seems like aptitude is mixing up versions for packages from 2 different architectures (see insert). Can someone explain what's going on?

It seems to me it's finding a conflict between libsystemd0 and libsystemd0:arm64. Why do these packages from different architectures have a common dependency 237-3ubuntu10[.3]?

```
# sudo aptitude install libdbus-1-dev:arm64

The following NEW packages will be installed:

  gcc-8-base:arm64{a} libc6:arm64{a} libdbus-1-3:arm64{a} libdbus-1-dev:arm64 libgcc1:arm64{a} libgcrypt20:arm64{a} 
  libgpg-error0:arm64{a} liblz4-1:arm64{a} liblzma5:arm64{a} libsystemd0:arm64{ab} 

0 packages upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Need to get 879 kB/3,283 kB of archives. After unpacking 13.3 MB will be used.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 libsystemd0 : Breaks: libsystemd0:arm64 (!= 237-3ubuntu10.3) but 237-3ubuntu10 is to be installed
 libsystemd0:arm64 : Breaks: libsystemd0 (!= 237-3ubuntu10) but 237-3ubuntu10.3 is installed

open: 47; closed: 1301; defer: 19; conflict: 29
```

Comment: Typically, they shouldn't conflict as long as both packages contain `Multi-Arch: same`. Could you include the output of `apt-cache show libsystemd0` and `apt-cache show libsystemd0:arm64`? Does the problem persist after running `sudo apt update && sudo apt install --reinstall libsystemd0:arm64 libsystemd0`? On my system I'm not getting any conflict between the two libsystemd0 packages but they're both at version 229-4ubuntu21.8 on Ubuntu 16.04.4.